# Bitbake build for yocto failed on adding libgdiplus

Tags: yocto, bitbake

We are building a yocto image with bitbake.
In the build we need to add libgdiplus, but this causes an error during the build.
This is the error:

> ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'libgdiplus' (but ***/***/***/sources/meta-variscite-fslc/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-gui.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
> NOTE: Runtime target 'libgdiplus' is unbuildable, removing...
> Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['libgdiplus']
> NOTE: Target 'fsl-image-gui' is unbuildable, removing...
> Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['fsl-image-gui', 'libgdiplus']
> ERROR: Required build target 'fsl-image-gui' has no buildable providers.
> Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['fsl-image-gui', 'libgdiplus']

In our bblayers.conf file we've added the meta-mono layer

```
LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../..')}"

BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-distro \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-qt5 \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-swupdate \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-virtualization \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-variscite-fslc \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-security \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-dotnet-core \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-mono \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-tempest-driverboard \
"
```

In our layer.conf file We try to do a CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL for libgdiplus(this is the one that fails).

```
...

    CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "giflib"
    
    CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "libgdiplus"
```

Are there some other dependencies that need to be installed, or is there another easier way to get libgdiplus in the build?
I'm quite new in yocto so any help is welcome.

Comment: Possibly the meta-mono files are not present where you think they are?  Try to inspect the layers using `bitbake-layers show-layers` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178057/bitbake-how-does-the-build-system-choose-the-recipe-provided-by-more-than-one-l)

Comment: meta-mono is indeed not there when I do bitbake-layers show-layers, all the other BBLayers are. Now let's figure out why :-)

Comment: Looks like we retrieved a wrong revision of the bblayers.config file. Thanks voyager42 to put me on the right track